# String array getter Method with for loop

Tags: java, arrays

I got a simple getter Method for a String Array. The Problem is, that the method return just one element instead of all 6.
Here is the Code:

```
    public String names() {

   String[] strings = new String[]{

            "name 1",
            "name 2",
            "name 3",
            "name 4",
            "name 5",
            "name 6"


    };

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        return strings[i];

    }
    return null;
}
```

The returned element is always the first one.. Can somebody explain me, why is doesn't return the whole array?

Comment: Because your return type is `String` instead of `String[]`, and you are returning the element 0 of your array (i.e. your iteration takes place only once and then returns).

Comment: It doesn't return the whole array because you are telling it to `return strings[i];` and as soon as it executes this once (for `i ==0`), it returns the indicated value. Also, as Mena points out, you can't return the whole array if the return type is `String`; it would have to be `String[]` (unless you wanted to mash all the values into a single `String` representation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first iteration of the loop, when `i` equals `0`, the method exits executing `return strings[0]`, which is `name1`.

If you want to return the whole array, you do not need a loop, simply do `return strings`.

Comment: ... and change the return type, I think. Unless compiling is an option :D

Answer (score 1):

Issue is over here :

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    return strings[i];
}
```

For when for loop starts, it initialises i to 0 and i < your length of string array so it enters loop and returns strings[0].

Answer (score 1):

because you are return first element.you can't return all throw the array in this way.because when you return it exit from method retuning first value
if you want to return all 
then use following code. make sure return type is `String[]`. instead `String`

```
public String[] names() {

   String[] strings = new String[]{

            "name 1",
            "name 2",
            "name 3",
            "name 4",
            "name 5",
            "name 6"


    };


    return strings;
}
```

Comment: That's not going to work unless you change the return type of the method.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, it just returned  the Array it self(lJava.lang.string:some numbers) and not the Strings. No idea how you call that but i solved it by returning`return Arrays.toString(strings);` Also by leaving the return type String.

Comment: @Brokenwings if you use Arrays.toString(strings) then it store all elements in a string so you can return as String .if you use return String then you can use same method to convert your array to String.i didn't know that you want to return a string with all elements.and you can also use Arrays.toString(names()); in this case

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the return type of the method to `String[]`, and, instead of making a loop, just `return strings`